# Wordpress Gallery Thumbnail images look blurry

Tags: gallery, thumbnails

I am using the standard WP gallery, and it all looks great on the page until I have images with different sizes. I have resized al the images I could and set them to medium size display  and those look great, but some galleries have portrait and landscape images so I cannot resize these to be uniform.

My main issue is if I choose thumbnail, the images look really blurry, and if I choose medium the layout is misaligned.

Does anyone know of a plugin that can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

luckily I found the answer shortly after posting this question. My thumbnail size setting (Settings/Media) was 150 x 150px - cropped.

So when I displayed them on my page, desktop size, in a row of 4, the thumbnails were getting stretched to 282 x 282px.

I changed it to this new size and used a Rebuild Thumbnail plugin and it looks great now. It scales down nicely so just set it to the maximum size it will be on desktop and it'll display flawlessly.

Cheers